# Relation of equivalence

Tags: relations

I need help solving this task, if anyone had a similar problem it would help me.

The task is :

Show that the relation $\rho$ is introduced on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ in the following way $(x,y)\in\rho \iff  $exists $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that it is $x-y=nk$ where is $n\ge 2$ natural number. Determine the relation of equivalence and equivalence class.

I tried this:

For relation equivalence:

Reflexivity:

$x-x=nk\iff 0=nk \iff k=0, x\rho x$

Symmetry:

$x-y=nk\iff -y+x=nk, y\rho x$

Transitivity:

$x \rho y \land y\rho z\\x-y=nk \land -z+y=nk\\(x-y)+(-z+y)=nk\\x-z=nk$

I don't know if this is good at all?
I don't even know how to start equivalence classes..
Thanks in advance !

Comment: For symm: $-nk$

Comment: For trans: $x−y=nk$ and $−z+y=-nh$ thus: $x-z=(k-h)n$

Comment: For equivalence class, try some small examples of $n$, it will be clear soon

Comment: Is this right now, for relation equivalence ?   Reflexsivity:  $x-x=nk\iff 0=nk\iff k=0, x\rho x$ Symmetry:$x-y=nk\iff -y+x=-nk, y\rho x$        Transitivity:$x-y=nk \land -z+y=-nh\\\(x-z)=(k-h)n, x\rho z$